# Git Extensions removing large files fails

Tags: git, git-extensions

When using the plugin under Windows I tried different approaches for the bash script to not fail calling Git.

Still I always get this error:

```
>for /F %a IN ('"C:\PROGRA~1\Git\bin\git.exe" for-each-ref --format "%^(refname^)" refs/original/') DO "C:\PROGRA~1\Git\bin\git.exe" update-ref -d %a
Command "C:\PROGRA~1\Git\bin\git.exe" for-each-ref --format "%(refname)" is wrong or could not be found.
```

I changed the path in setting to

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Git\bin\git.exe
```

I thought the space is making trouble under windows, but that was not the problem.